# Are the new Team System 2010 features available with the 2008 server?

Tags: tfs

Team System 2010 has some new features that really interest me including branched history, rollback, and baseless merge.  Are these features available with just the new Team System Client, or do I have to upgrade my TFS server to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [baseless merges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx) in TFS 2008. Rollback is built into TFS 2010, but is also available in the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) for TFS 2008. The new branch features are only available in TFS 2010 (you'll need to upgrade your server). The good news it that upgrading your server is fairly straightforward and there's an update for Team Explorer 2008 that improves its compatibility with TFS 2010.